# How to write an image url in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write and image url using javascript 'after'
Example:

```
$("#product_availbility_msg").after("<img src=" + https://www.heals.com/media/wysiwyg/top_nav/xmas.jpg + ">");
```

Any idea why id this not working?

Comment: Yes, the quotes are not correct. Use `$("#product_availbility_msg").after('<img src=" + https://www.heals.com/media/wysiwyg/top_nav/xmas.jpg + ">');` **1.** Use smart editor that'll spot these mistakes at first place **2.** Use jslint/jshint **3.** Always see console for error when something is not working

Comment: Strings need to be in quotes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your website URL is also a string, so you don't need to use String interpolation there:

```
$("#product_availbility_msg").after('<img src="https://www.heals.com/media/wysiwyg/top_nav/xmas.jpg">');
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you please check  https://fiddle.jshell.net/njxyy1gs/

Comment: @SheikhSiddiquee You have a typo in your HTML, you're using `is` instead of `id`. Look at your fiddle updated: https://fiddle.jshell.net/njxyy1gs/1/